# Stuck while downloading meteor package

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-meteor

Meteor package download stuck. Is there any fix? I tried to download package separately, but it still does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a spelling error. Run this instead:

```
meteor add angular2-html-templates
```

Comment: Hi @Jonty Shady if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: hey @muetzerich
i restart the project using 'meteor'
now it stuck again on 'Downloading angular2-compilers@0.6.0..'